# iOS -- I wanna change language alert push notification

Tags: ios, notifications

I'm using push notification on iOS, when you install my app at iPhone or iPad, it alerts like the following image:

[image]

I want to change the language from English to any language.

Help me! thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That is an iOS native alert prompt which you do not have control over and you cannot change what it says. With that said, this alert text is set by the language the user has chosen in **iOS Settings > General > International > Language**.

Comment: oh no, I have been installed one app using unicode utf8 when language in general using English. I don't know why?, i think language in alert from Push notification can change without change ios setting.

Comment: No, this alert is an iOS native alert and is not generated from a push notification at all, it's just a dialog iOS presents to you to get permission for the app to receive push notifications. There are some bugs I have seen in iOS where not all prompts are localized for some strange reason, but this text /should be/ localized depending on the language of the iOS device and you have no control over the localization of this text or the text itself.